# Vue - Call Function from facebook button inside Vue-Component

Tags: vue.js

trying to implement the Facebook-Login button inside of a vue component. How can I call a function on the the surrounding component from the custom attribute "onLogin" from the button?

#### HTML

```
<complogin :page="page" inline-template v-if="page=='login'">
   <div data-max-rows="1" onlogin="fbLogin()" data-size="medium" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" class="div fb-login-button"></div>
</complogin>
```

#### JS

```
Vue.component('complogin',{
   data: function() {
       return { foo: "bar" }
   },
   methods: {
       fbLogin:function() {
           console.log("Hello!")
       },
    }
})
```

Comment: Maybe show your component structure with more code? Currently there's no *surrounding* here.

Comment: @PanJunjie潘俊杰 There you go, thanks!

Comment: How will `onlogin` be triggered? If it were `onclick`, the question would be quite clear.

Comment: Its the Facebook-Loginbutton. So its getting triggered by the facebook-script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution:

Attached the Component-Method via lifecycle hook to the window event and then just called it.

```
loaded: function() {
    window.componentMethod = this.componentMethod
}
```

Comment: I just stumbled upon this old post of mine. I honestly don´t really understand the problem myself anymore, haha. I think I wanted to handle the login-callback from this wrapper-component on the outside. Obviously attaching something to the window-object is quite stupid. Just emit an event, stupid past-me! this.$emit("login", payload) and listen for it on the outside of the comp with @login="...". Also, why would I use an inline-template? Jeeez... x)